# Inhertiance in Solidity and Cryptozombies: How can I deploy a full OOP tree?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I'm working my way through the cryptozombies tutorial and ran into a conceptual snag. It seems that the "ZombieFactory" contract is meant to be a singleton contract that contains the global state for our hypothetical cryptozombies game, which it holds in a few arrays and mappings, but it's not clear to me that all the child contracts will be pointing to the same registry when deployed without some extra work.

The children contracts often refer to the state held in their parent contracts (ie ZombieFactory) which, at least in the context of cryptozombies, seems to be assumed to be a singleton. This doesn't mesh with my conceptual model of OOP, where each instantiation of a subclass includes its own closure for all its state (including the state variables declared in its parents). It seems like (absent of some careful deployment), deploying multiple contracts connected in an OOP hierarchy (esp a when that hierarchy is a tree, not a linked list) could be problematic. How do I know that I'm not declaring a different instance each time?

In this case, how can I ensure that the contracts are deployed in a way that behaves as described in the first part of my question? Do you need to hold the address of the parent contract in a field?

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to deploy only the final class. Let's say you have A, which is parent for B and B is parent for C. Then you deploy C to the network, but you will also provide source code for A and B, so compiler would compile A, B and C classes into one chunk of bycode and upload it to the network. As a result you would have only one instance of the contract, which have all methods/fields of A, B and C.
It is possible to upload contract as separate instances, but then they are libraries and used via composition, not inheritance.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Gotcha. If I want all children to inherit from the same Singleton parent contract (aka shared state), I should instead use that parent as a library?

Comment: @ashissl, [library](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html#libraries) is a contract with no state in EVM, so It is not going to work for you. If you want to share state between multiple contracts. You have to make a master contract which owns the state and all children contract should interact with it using interfaces.

Comment: Essentially, composition over inheritance.

Comment: Got it! Thanks! For some reason I assumed the class hierarchy in the cryptozombies tutorial was a tree, whereas in reality it was a linked list. In that case, is it still against convention to use inheritance (and use just deploy the lowest object in the hiearchy once).

Comment: @ashissl. Inheritance usage is absolutely normal, in fact it is the most common approach in Solidity. Just deploy your target class and it will have all functionality and single state.